# help! I pulled a bonsai seedling gently and it broke off, can it survive?

Tags: seeds, bonsai

So I saw a bonsai seedling and I touched it gently, it broke off. I don’t know what to do[image]

Comment: Oops..a young plant with roots gone, I don't think it will survive :(

Comment: What bonsai is it? It looks like bell pepper.

Comment: Bin it - it can't survive without a root.